# jQuery Plupload Queue - Dont show the file Browser if Input have no text

Tags: javascript, jquery, plupload

I do not want to show the file browser if the input does not contain any text.

This is my code...

```
var haveText = false;
$('#input_box').bind('change',function(){
    if($(this).val()) {
        haveText = true;
    } else {
        haveText = false;
    }
});

$('a.plupload_add').click(function(e) {
    uploader.trigger("DisableBrowse", true);

    if(haveText) {
        $(this).unbind('click');
        uploader.trigger("Refresh");
        uploader.trigger("DisableBrowse", true);
        uploader.trigger("DisableBrowse", false);
    } else {
        alert("no test");
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

What should I change to do what I require?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could just toggle the browse button visibility when your textbox changes value :

```
$('#input_box').bind('change',function(){
    if($(this).val()!=='') {
        $("a.plupload_add").show();
    } else {
        $("a.plupload_add").hide();
    }
});
```